# Sort data from a flat file by column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, netcat

I store my data in a flat file in the following way:

```
1|$item|$price|$quality|$keywords
```

Which looks like this in reality:

```
1|Shoes|50|5|Classy,basic
3|Shirt|25|4|Simple
2|Tshirt|20|1|Basic, urban
4|Coat|45|3|Classy, preppy
```

I'm trying to sort the data by one of the columns of my choice, let's say by *price*. Here is the file called by an ajax function which lists the data:

```
$cat_file = "data.php";
$cat_db = file("$cat_file");
$call = fopen("$cat_file","r");
foreach($cat_db as $cat_line) {
$cat_line_arr = explode("|",$cat_line);
$cat_line_id = $cat_line_arr[1];
    if($cat_line_id == $cat) {

       $id = $cat_line_arr[0];
       $item = $cat_line_arr[1];
       $price = $cat_line_arr[2];
       $quality = $cat_line_arr[3];
       $keywords = $cat_line_arr[4];

        if (BLABLABLACONDITION) {

        *LISTS THE DATA SORTED THE WAY I WANT*

        }
    }
}
fclose($call);
```

My code above works fine, but there is no specific sorting, it just lists the data in its original order from the file.
Here is the result I want to get if I sort by *price* and *descending order* for example:

```
1|Shoes|50|5|Classy,basic
4|Coat|45|3|Classy, preppy
3|Shirt|25|4|Simple
2|Tshirt|20|1|Basic, urban
```

What sould I replace *LISTS THE DATA SORTED THE WAY I WANT* with to sort the data ? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// read file as string and turn into an array, 1 element per line
$records = explode("\n", file_get_contents('path/to/file'));

// turn each line into an array, 1 element per field
array_walk($records, function (&$record) { $record = explode('|', $record); });

//$records is now a two-dimensional array containing the data

// gather the prices into a new array
$prices = array_map(function ($record) { return (int) $record[2]; }, $records);

// use the prices to sort the records
array_multisort($prices, SORT_ASC, $records);

foreach ($records as $record) {
   //... do your thing.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kobbe explained your code to me, I'm going to have a closer look at it ! =D

Comment: Your welcome. I'll add some comments to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you soo much ! This is very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your questions, so just guessing here, are you looking for krsort() and ksort()?

```
$cat_line_id = $cat_line_arr[0];
$cat_line_item = $cat_line_arr[1];
$cat_line_price = $cat_line_arr[2];
```

etc...

```
ksort($cat_line_price);
```

rearrange array according to price in ascending order

```
krsort($cat_line_price);
```

rearrange array according to price in decending order

Comment: It looks like what I'm looking for ! I'm trying to sort my array by a certain column of my choice, example, price in ascending order by keeping the correlation to the rest of the line.

I tried using your snippets just like this in my code, but I get an error (ksort expects parameter etc), how should I implement this to work ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, went shopping, this is an example from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_ksort.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help; I had a look and my issue is that I don't understand how my data translates into the array structure every tutorial shows; from what I understand, they all have 2 columns while I have many and would like to sort by another column than the first one (which is why ksort does ?). I guess this time I'm trying to tackle something wayyyy above my level of coding lol

Comment: Actually, OscarJ gave the right answer. You are dealing with a multidimensional array (OscarJ explodes in into a multidimensional array). Simply look up each php function he used in his example. As each item uses a line, he used explode() with each line (\n) as separator on the file set in file_get_contents('path/to/file'), which fetches the file as a string. OscarJ then uses array_walk() to run each element (each line in your record) of the array in a function. What he does in this function is explode() each of the elements (of the $records array) into other arrays, using | as separator.

Comment: Then, array_map is used to send each value (of each array ($record) inside the main array ($records) to a function that selects $record[2] (the price), thus creating a new multidimensional array where the key to each subarray is now the price (not the ID as in the original file). OscarJ then uses array_multisort() to sort the array (numerically or alphabetically).

Comment: I see, I didn't comment because I wasn't sure if I understood his code well, thank you very very much for your explanations, I'm going to study this ! =D